# How Can I Fix Sublime Text CSS Style italic to Normal?

Tags: html, css, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

[image: see this image for better understanding]

I want to make it normal style without italic version. how can I achieve this, please solve me this. this italic version makes me so anger. now I want to make it simple and without italic version.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a solution for your issue on the **[Sublime Text forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/removing-font-styles-in-syntax/3795/2)**. Here's how you can fix it:

```
Open your colorscheme by navigating to Preferences > Browse Packages > Colorscheme - Default > NAME_OF_COLORSCHEME.tmTheme.

Perform a find and replace operation:

Find: Italic
Replace: Regular
```

This should resolve the problem you're facing. Let me know if you need further assistance!

Comment: Is that a BING AI answer?

Comment: Hello @mplungjan , I didn't use AI like bing or etc,  I kust wrote answer so clean therefore, It look likes ai wrote that answer.

Comment: Based on how you spell in the comment above, I doubt it...

Comment: Just for clarity; if you were to open the file that you specify here, it A) would not work because the defaults are `sublime-color-theme` and not `tmTheme` files and B) they would not be editable because you would be opening them from within their `sublime-package` file. The post you referenced it from 2012 and for Sublime Text 2. If you read further down that post, the actual answer to the question (or one of them) is there